# Gromov-Hausdorff distance between graphs with edges as part of the space versus not part of the space

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be finite simple graphs viewed as metric spaces in the natural way where the edges are *not* part of the space. Let $G_1'$ and $G_2'$ be copies of $G_1$ and $G_2$ resp. but with the edges included in the space. Is it necessarily true that $$d_{GH}(G_1', G_2') \geq d_{GH}(G_1, G_2)$$
where $d_{GH}$ is the [Gromov-Hausdorff Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%E2%80%93Hausdorff_convergence)?

Comment: what happens for the example where $G_1$ is a circle with $n$ edges and $G_2$ is a circle with $n+1$ edges?

Comment: Just for formulation, you could define $G_i$ as the 1-skeleton and $G_i^0$ as its 0-skeleton; the question is then whether $G_i\mapsto G_i^0$ is 1-Lipschitz.

Comment: @HenrikRüping yes it works: let $\Delta_n$ be the circle with $n$ edges. Then clearly $d(\Delta_i^0,\Delta_j^0)\ge 1/2$ for $i<j$ (since otherwise two vertices of $\Delta_j$ would be at distance $<1/2$ of the same vertex of $\Delta_i$). But it is easy to see that $d(\Delta_3,\Delta_4)\le 1/4$.

Comment: @HenrikRüping I think you might be right that that is a counter-example. I thought of that but did the calculation and somehow thought that the obvious imbedding for the with edges case gave $\frac{1}{2}$.